# Yii2 Tinymce Widget File/Image Upload Issue

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, widget, tinymce

I am using the DosAmigos Yii2 Tinymcs Widget to initiate tinymce on a text area.  Since I am using a widget the initiation setup is in PHP (See Below).  My issue is that the 'file_picker_callback' needs a javascript function NOT a string to work.  For example with quote marks, 'file_picker_callback'=>"function(callback, value, meta){...}" gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: fileBrowserCallback.call is not a function" error in the browser Console.  However without quotes, 'file_picker_callback'=>function(callback, value, meta){...} is not syntactically correct in PHP so it generates a syntax error.  How can I do this part of the initialization in PHP?  If I cannot do it in PHP, where does the javascript/jQuery need to go to initialize the 'file_picker_callback'.  How do I put it there?

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'page_content')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 50],
    'language' => 'en_CA',
    'clientOptions' => [
        //'inline' => true,
        'content_css' => $content_css,
        'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "image imagetools spellchecker visualchars textcolor",
            "autosave colorpicker hr nonbreaking template"
        ],
        'toolbar1' => "undo redo | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic",
        'toolbar2' => "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        'image_advtab' => true,
        'templates' => [
            [ 'title'=>'Test template 1', 'content'=>'Test 1' ],
            [ 'title'=>'Test template 2', 'content'=>'Test 2' ]
        ],
        'visualblocks_default_state'=>true,

        'images_upload_url'=>'postAcceptor.php',
        // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
        'file_picker_types'=>'image',
        // and here's our custom image picker
        'file_picker_callback'=>"function(callback, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, reader.result);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                    // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
                    callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
            };
            input.click();
        }"
    ]
]);?>
```

Comment: Try using [JsExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsexpression.html).

Comment: Using new JsExpression("function string") was the answer.  Thank you @InsaneSkull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who wish to see a working answer, I have posted one below.  @InsaneSkull gave the key (using JsExpression) to getting the code to work.

```
    $myDateTime = new DateTime();
    $content_css = [
            '/backend/assets/3be5f0f5/css/bootstrap.css?' . $myDateTime->getTimestamp(), ];

    <?= $form->field($model, 'page_content')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 50],
    'language' => 'en_CA',
    'clientOptions' => [
        //'inline' => true,
        //$content_css needs to be defined as "" or some css rules/files
        'content_css' => $content_css,
        'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "image imagetools spellchecker visualchars textcolor",
            "autosave colorpicker hr nonbreaking template"
        ],
        'toolbar1' => "undo redo | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic",
        'toolbar2' => "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        'image_advtab' => true,
        'templates' => [
            [ 'title'=>'Test template 1', 'content'=>'Test 1' ],
            [ 'title'=>'Test template 2', 'content'=>'Test 2' ]
        ],
        'visualblocks_default_state'=>true,
        'image_title' => true,
        'images_upload_url'=>'postAcceptor.php',
        // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
        'file_picker_types'=>'image',
        // and here's our custom image picker
        'file_picker_callback'=> new JsExpression("function(callback, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

            //If this is not included, the onchange function will not
            //be called the first time a file is chosen 
            //(at least in Chrome 58)
            var foo = document.getElementById('cms-page_content_ifr');
            foo.appendChild(input);

            input.onchange = function() {
                //alert('File Input Changed');
                //console.log( this.files[0] );

                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
                    // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
                    // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.

                    //Remove the first period and any thing after it 
                    var rm_ext_regex = /(\.[^.]+)+/;
                    var fname = file.name;
                    fname = fname.replace( rm_ext_regex, '');

                    //Make sure filename is benign
                    var fname_regex = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+([-_])*([A-Za-z0-9-_]*)$/;
                    if( fname_regex.test( fname ) ) {
                        var id = fname + '-' + (new Date()).getTime(); //'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, reader.result);
                        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
                        callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert( 'Invalid file name' );
                    }
                };
                //To get get rid of file picker input
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            };

            input.click();
        }")
    ]
]);?>
```

Comment: how can I upload file in yii2?

Comment: I cannot find postAcceptor.php anywhere. where is it

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt You have to create it.  You write it to do whatever you want to do with the images.  It resides on your server.

This code was written for a Yii2 framework website.  It supposed to be used with TinyMce.